# How to add index to existing column using alembic

Tags: python, alembic

Im new to python alembic .want to add index to existing column in particular table i did that but struck in creating alembic file for that.
ex:

```
class File(db.model):
        __tablename__ = 'file'
        id = db.column(db.ForeignKey('public.id.id),index = True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_index

Answer (score 0):

```
def upgrade():
     # op.execute('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name (column_name)')  # Mysql Raw Query
     op.create_index('index_name', 'table_name', ['column_name'], unique=False)

def downgrade():
    # op.execute('ALTER TABLE table_name DROP INDEX index_name')  # Mysql Raw Query
    op.drop_index('index_name', 'table_name')
```

Source:

[Upgrade - Add Index](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_index)
[Downgrade - Drop Index](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.drop_index)